# Routing table change notification on Mac OS X

Tags: macos

I would like to monitor routing table changes on Mac OS X. Is there any way to catch the changes of the routing table? Just like API `NotifyRouteChange` on Microsoft Windows, which would causes a notification to be sent to the caller whenever a change occurs in the IPv4 routing table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well,i turned to route(8) command source code, and i found the modifier 'monitor'. "sudo route monitor"